# Make error on PerlMagick 6.8.6

Tags: makefile, fatal-error, perlmagick

Attempting to install the CPAN Image::Magick module and am getting a fatal error that a core file is missing (note the fatal error highlighted between horizontal lines):

```
Reading '/Users/coblem/.cpan/Metadata'
Database was generated on Sat, 27 Jul 2013 18:29:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Image::Magick'
Running make for J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/coblem/.cpan/sources/authors/id/J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz ok

CPAN.pm: Building J/JC/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lperl
Writing Makefile for Image::Magick
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp Magick.pm blib/lib/Image/Magick.pm
AutoSplitting blib/lib/Image/Magick.pm (blib/lib/auto/Image/Magick)
/opt/local/bin/perl5.12 /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/ExtUtils/xsubpp -typemap      /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/ExtUtils/typemap -typemap typemap Magick.xs > Magick.xsc && mv  Magick.xsc Magick.c
/usr/bin/clang -c -I/usr/local/include/ImageMagick-6 -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 - DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I"/usr/include/ImageMagick-6" -pipe -O2 - fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -I/opt/local/include -no-cpp-precomp -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack- protector -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -fopenmp -g -O2 -Wall -pthread - DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -O3 -DVERSION=\"6.86\" - DXS_VERSION=\"6.86\" "-I/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.12.4/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE" -  D_LARGE_FILES=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H Magick.c
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-fopenmp'
```

---

```
Magick.xs:60:10: fatal error: 'magick/MagickCore.h' file not found
```

---

```
#include <magick/MagickCore.h>
^
1 error generated.
make: *** [Magick.o] Error 1
JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.86.tar.gz
/usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
Can't test without successful make
Running make install
Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Thoughts on what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install `ImageMagick-devel` package (with `MagickCore.h` header file).

Comment: Well, I have ImageMagick itself installed.  Since this is the Perl API module, does the "devel" package suggestion still apply?  ImageMagick itself is working...